# When click back button(IOS) or back hardware (Android)on the logging screen user Navigate to the Main Route. in salesforce react native

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, salesforce-sdk-android

when clicking the back button on the logging screen navigates to the main router screens but is not synced to no action how  to prevent the user from navigating to the main route by clocking the back handler in Android or clicking the back icon on the logging page in iOS
in salesforce react-native
#react-native #SDK